# How to get Plugin's dependencies in custom SBT task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to create custom SBT task, and I need to get Plugin dependencies in it. The task goal is to create .zip with all the .jars the Plugin needs. I can get the Plugin's settings, and there are some like `fullClasspath`, but how to get it's value? There is method `init`, which returns `Initialize`, which in turn has method `evaluate`, but it needs `Settings[Scope]`. Where to get `Settings[Scope]` from?

Or is there any other way to get Plugin's dependencies?